# Access violation exception thrown when trying to start Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics

Tags: visual-studio, graphics

I recently tried to set up Visual Studio 2022 for developing DirectX 11 apps on my new laptop. I copied a few DirectX solutions from my old machine onto the new one and they all worked fine, except for when I tried to debug them using the Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics.

Whenever I try to debug an app using the graphics debugger, it works for a moment until an access violation exception from `D3D12Core.dll` comes my way.

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD83745D20 (D3D12Core.dll) in DummyVSGD.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Graphics Diagnostics component - Nothing changed.

Turning on "Exception Settings -> C++ Exceptions -> <All C++ Exceptions not in this list>", breaking the code at the first exception, yields `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x0000002419FFFB10.`

I found [this](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Iris-Xe-Help-Emulator-Most-common-failure-create-D3Device/m-p/1295201) forum post on the intel forums talking about the difficulties of using the Iris Xe with DirectX, so I set my default GPU to my NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, however, nothing changed.

I'm also quite confused about why the Diagnostics would use D3D12 dlls when the graphics debugger itself doesn't even support D3D12 anymore?

I'm using

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.6.5
- CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12500H
- GPU 0: Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
- GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU

Debug Output:

```
...
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFA20.
The thread 0xd84 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'DummyVSGD.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_ec5e4cdfcd3a62b8\igdinfo64.dll'
'DummyVSGD.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_ec5e4cdfcd3a62b8\igd11dxva64.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFC50.
The thread 0x68dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFDE0.
The thread 0x5448 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFC00.
The thread 0x2ab8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFB50.
The thread 0x54a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFAA0.
The thread 0x1df8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFA30.
The thread 0x3054 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FF870.
The thread 0x7140 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFB50.
The thread 0x257c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FF800.
The thread 0x2764 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFD70.
The thread 0x5e3c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFC40.
The thread 0x36cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFA20.
The thread 0x35d0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFBF0.
The thread 0x5f90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FFE10.
The thread 0x3550 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FFE10.
The thread 0x1154 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::DdiThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF5FF690.
The thread 0x23b8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDCC254B2C in DummyVSGD.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: MONZA::IgcThreadingContext<MONZA::AdapterTraits_Gen12LP>::msg_end at memory location 0x00000081EF4FF6F0.
The thread 0x2e6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
...
'DummyVSGD.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll'. 
'DummyVSGD.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d9on12.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD83745D20 (D3D12Core.dll) in DummyVSGD.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The program '[11472] DummyVSGD.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Stack:

```
D3D12Core.dll!Unknown::QueryInterface<struct IDXGIAdapter>(struct IDXGIAdapter * *)
D3D12Core.dll!D3D12ValidateAndCreateDevice()
D3D12.dll!00007ffdc41a6a4d()
DXCaptureReplay.dll!00007ffd239384b6()
DXCaptureReplay.dll!00007ffd23a055d6()
DXCaptureReplay.dll!00007ffd23a4c09f()
DXCaptureReplay.dll!00007ffd23a4c26d()
DXCaptureReplay.dll!00007ffd23991dcd()
D3D12.dll!00007ffdc41a668e()
d3d90n12.dll!00007ffda701b960()
d3d90n12.dll!00007ffda7095a2b()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbb0123eb()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafc3853()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafc2acd()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafc569a()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafd62ac()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafd5ed8()
d3d9.dll!00007ffdbafec43e()
dxdiagn.dll!00007ffd3a23d75d()
dxdiagn.dll!00007ffd3a21ff30()
dxdiagn.dll!00007ffd3a2051ae()
dxdiagn.dll!00007ffd3a20a88f()
dxdiagn.dll!00007ffd3a20a54a()
VsGraphicsExperiment.dll!00007ffd3b219587()
VsGraphicsExperiment.dll!00007ffd3b1fce1a()
VsGraphicsExperiment.dll!00007ffd3b1fcefd()
ntdll.dll!00007ffdceadca01()
ntdll.dll!00007ffdceac5976()
kernel32.dll!00007ffdcd7026ad()
ntdll.dll!00007ffdceaeaa68()
```

DummyVSGD.cpp:

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <exception>

#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "dxgi.lib")

#define WIDTH 480
#define HEIGHT 360

HWND hwnd = nullptr; // Handle to instance of the window

ID3D11Device *device = nullptr;
ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext = nullptr;

inline void ThrowIfFailed(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
}

bool InitializeDirect3d11App(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    // Create DXGI factory to enumerate adapters
    IDXGIFactory1* DXGIFactory;

    ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**)&DXGIFactory));

    // Use the first adapter
    IDXGIAdapter1* Adapter;

    ThrowIfFailed(DXGIFactory->EnumAdapters1(0, &Adapter));

    DXGIFactory->Release();

    //Create our Direct3D 11 Device
    ThrowIfFailed(D3D11CreateDevice(Adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, nullptr, &deviceContext));

    //Release the Adapter interface
    Adapter->Release();

    return true;
}

// Main message handler for the sample.
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    // Handle any messages the switch statement didn't.
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

_Use_decl_annotations_
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Initialize the window class.
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = { 0 };
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.lpszClassName = L"DXSampleClass";
    RegisterClassEx(&windowClass);

    RECT windowRect = { 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    // Create the window and store a handle to it.
    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        windowClass.lpszClassName,
        L"Title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
        windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top,
        nullptr,        // We have no parent window.
        nullptr,        // We aren't using menus.
        hInstance,
        nullptr);       // Additional data.

    // Initialize D3D11
    if (!InitializeDirect3d11App(hInstance))    //Initialize Direct3D
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Direct3D Initialization - Failed",
            L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Main sample loop.
    MSG msg = {};
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        // Process any messages in the queue.
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    // Return this part of the WM_QUIT message to Windows.
    return static_cast<char>(msg.wParam);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics tool definitely doesn't support DX12 (where PIX should be used instead), and I wouldn't be surprised if it has also stopped supporting DX11 too on Windows 11. I don't know why Microsoft hasn't removed Graphics Diagnostics from Visual Studio if it's clearly an outdated and unsupported feature.